# React Speedometer or gauge. How to created labelled speedometer in react?

Tags: reactjs, charts, gauge

I have used this library to draw speedometer. https://github.com/palerdot/react-d3-speedometer
I want to set label on each segment. Please help if there is any other library to draw chart like this.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the answer on that issue it's not doable: [Is it possible to set label on segments](https://github.com/palerdot/react-d3-speedometer/issues/14)

*`Currently the labels are automatically calculated based on maxValue, 'minValue' and segments. This may not be possible at all, as per the library functionality, there will be 5 values for your chart instead of 4 you have mentioned. I'm afraid this is not possible at all as far as I see. So I'm closing this issue.`*

There are many libraries that draw charts but each of them comes with its limitations, for my projects I ended up implementing the charts by myself, it's not so hard and lets you do exactly what you need without suffering the quirks.

Here is some code I extracted from my [ReactPie component](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/components/ReactPie), it draws a PieSegment so you could use that to create a similar result than the gauge pretty easily. You can try it in that pen: https://codepen.io/leefsmp/pen/dJjpXx

```
class ReactPieSegment extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {

      super (props)
    }

    generatePathDef(centre, rIn, rOut, start, delta) {

      const endRad = start + delta

      const startOut = {
        x: centre.x + rOut * Math.cos(start),
        y: centre.y + rOut * Math.sin(start)
      }

      const endOut = {
        x: centre.x + rOut * Math.cos(endRad),
        y: centre.y + rOut * Math.sin(endRad)
      }

      const startIn = {
        x: centre.x + rIn * Math.cos(endRad),
        y: centre.y + rIn * Math.sin(endRad)
      };

      var endIn = {
        x: centre.x + rIn * Math.cos(start),
        y: centre.y + rIn * Math.sin(start)
      }

      const largeArc = delta > Math.PI ? 1 : 0

      return (
        `M${startOut.x},${startOut.y}` +
        ` A${rOut},${rOut} 0 ` +
        `${largeArc},1 ${endOut.x},${endOut.y}` +
        ` L${startIn.x},${startIn.y}` +
        ` A${rIn},${rIn} 0 ` +
        `${largeArc},0 ${endIn.x},${endIn.y}` +
        ` L${startOut.x},${startOut.y} Z`
      )
    }

    render () {

      const {
        fillColor, strokeColor,
        start, delta,
        rIn, rOut,
        centre
      } = this.props

      const pathDef = this.generatePathDef(
        centre, rIn, rOut, start, delta)

      const labelDist = rIn + 1.2 * (rOut-rIn)

      const labelRad = start + 0.5 * delta

      const labelPos = {
        x: centre.x + labelDist * Math.cos (labelRad) - 10,
        y: centre.y + labelDist * Math.sin (labelRad)
      }

      const labelStyle = {
        transform: `translate(${labelPos.x}px, ${labelPos.y}px)`
      }

      return (
        <g className='react-pie-segment'>
          <path
            stroke={strokeColor}
            fill={fillColor}
            d={pathDef}
          />
          <text style={labelStyle}>
            {this.props.label}
          </text>
        </g>
      )
    }
  }


  class Demo extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
      super (props)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="demo">
          <svg>
          <ReactPieSegment
            centre={{x:150, y:150}}
            strokeColor={"green"}
            fillColor={"green"}
            delta={Math.PI/4}
            start={Math.PI}
            label={"label 1"}
            rOut={90}
            rIn={50}
          />
          <ReactPieSegment
            centre={{x:150, y:150}}
            strokeColor={"yellow"}
            fillColor={"yellow"}
            delta={Math.PI/4}
            start={5*Math.PI/4}
            label={"label 2"}
            rOut={90}
            rIn={50}
          /> 
          <ReactPieSegment
            centre={{x:150, y:150}}
            strokeColor={"orange"}
            fillColor={"orange"}
            delta={Math.PI/4}
            start={6*Math.PI/4}
            label={"label 3"}
            rOut={90}
            rIn={50}
          /> 
          <ReactPieSegment
            centre={{x:150, y:150}}
            strokeColor={"red"}
            fillColor={"red"}
            delta={Math.PI/4}
            start={7*Math.PI/4}
            label={"label 4"}
            rOut={90}
            rIn={50}
          /> 
          </svg>  
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  const root = document.getElementById('root')

  ReactDOM.render(<Demo/>, root)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Philippe. Do you have any idea to draw needle with it?

Comment: Well I would create a path that represents a triangle and a circle and merge them in the same svg group, then use code to apply rotation based on input value. You should take a look at how to work with svg path and circle primitives: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle

Comment: Thanks. I will check

Answer (score 1):

The main requirement mentioned here got sorted from the library itself.
Example: [react-speedometer--custom-segment-labels](https://palerdot.in/react-d3-speedometer/?path=/story/reactspeedometer--custom-segment-labels)